# How to custom form import file excel in Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, python-import, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to change file standard excel, so if I import that file and confirm it, then it will be error. How to custom form import file excel in odoo as: function in button have name confirm, how to get path upload file?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem a bit more in detail? FYI: Odoo can only import csv files.

Comment: I solved my problem. thank for comment